# How do I map and group_by at the same time?

Tags: elixir

As an example, let's say I have an enumerable `collection` of pairs `{first, second}`. Grouping these pairs using

```
Enum.group_by(collection, fn {first, second} -> first end)
```

will result in a `Map` whose keys are determined by the passed anonymous function. Its values are collections of pairs.
However, I would like its values to contain the pair's `second` elements instead.

---

In general, given an enumerable, I would like to group providing both a key extractor *and* a value mapper, so that I can determine what gets put into the resulting `Map`'s values. I.e., I would like something like

```
map_group_by(
  collection,
  fn {_first, second} -> second end,
  fn {first, _second} -> first end
)
```

where `collection`'s values are mapped before being grouped, yet where the key mapper still operates on the original elements.

*Is there such a function in the standard library? If not, what is the most idiomatic way to achieve this?*

---

I know I could do something like

```
Enum.reduce(
  collection,
  %{},
  fn({key, value}, acc) -> Dict.update(acc, key, [value], &([value | &1])) end
)
```

but this seems clunky and creates `[value]` lists preemptively (is that actually true?). Is there a better way that is both concise and efficient?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Elixir 1.3 there is now [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) that takes a `mapper_fun` argument, which solves exactly this problem:

```
Enum.group_by(enumerable, &elem(&1, 0), &elem(&1, 1))
```

---

*Obsolete answer:*

At this moment, there is no such function in the standard library. I ended up using this:

```
def map_group_by(enumerable, value_mapper, key_extractor) do
  Enum.reduce(Enum.reverse(enumerable), %{}, fn(entry, categories) ->
    value = value_mapper.(entry)
    Map.update(categories, key_extractor.(entry), [value], &[value | &1])
  end)
end
```

which can (for my example) then be called like this:

```
map_group_by(
  collection,
  fn {_, second} -> second end,
  fn {first, _} -> first end
)
```

It is adapted from the standard library's [`Enum.group_by`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1460).
Regarding the `[value]`: I don't know what the compiler can or cannot optimize, but at least this is what `Enum.group_by` does as well.

Note the `Enum.reverse` call, which was not in the example from my question. This ensures that the element order is preserved in the resulting value lists. If you do not need that order to be preserved (like I did in my case, in which I only wanted to sample from the result anyway), it can be dropped.

Answer (score 9):

## Real answer

Since Elixir 1.3 there is now `Enum.group_by/3` who's 3rd argument is a function that gets mapped over the keys.

---

## Obsolete Answer

But I'll give you my solution:

To start off, It's important to notice, as you see in Elixir Docs that a list of tuples is the same as a key-value list:

```
iex> list = [{:a, 1}, {:b, 2}]
[a: 1, b: 2]
iex> list == [a: 1, b: 2]
true
```

So with this in mind it's easy to use the `Enum.map` across it.

This does make two passes it it but it's a little cleaner looking than what you had:

```
defmodule EnumHelpers do
  def map_col(lst) do
    lst
    |> Enum.group_by(fn {x, _} -> x end)
    |> Enum.map(fn {x, y} -> {x, Dict.values y} end)
  end
end

IO.inspect EnumHelpers.map_col([a: 2, a: 3, b: 3])
```

which will print out:

```
[a: [3, 2], b: [3]]
```

---

Edit: **Faster Version**:

```
defmodule EnumHelpers do

  defp group_one({key, val}, categories) do
    Dict.update(categories, key, [val], &[val|&1])
  end

  def map_col_fast(coll) do
    Enum.reduce(coll, %{}, &group_one/2)
  end
end

IO.inspect EnumHelpers.map_col_fast([a: 2, a: 3, b: 3])
```

Comment: Just for clarification, this cannot use `Map.values` because it's not working on a list of tuples rather than a real "Map".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not what I was looking for: as you note, this makes a second pass, but more importantly, it also creates an intermediate collection. It is therefore unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @user4235730, I added a version that should suit your fancy. Note that however the Erlang VM never modifies memory in place and thus it will create intermediate collections no matter what, although this isn't such a problem with immutable values because it can reference the unchanged parts of the old version to some extent (if it works at all like Clojure).

Comment: What I meant by the intermediate collection was that your first solution creates an additional map that has different values from the final result, which means that there is (as far as I can tell) no structural sharing going on.