# How to perform a join on tuples in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
  def pairs do
    person_a = %{name: :a}
    person_b = %{name: :b}
    [{person_a, 1}, {person_b, 5}, {person_a, 2}, {person_b, 6}, {person_a, 3}]
  end
```

And I want to join them based on the name of the person, resulting in this:

```
[{%{name: :a}, [1, 2, 3]}, {%{name: :b}, [5, 6]}]
```

I'm able to accomplish this with the following code:

```
  def group_pairs do
    pairs
    |> Enum.group_by(fn {f, _s} -> f.name end)
    |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} ->
      {elem(List.first(v), 0), Enum.map(v, &elem(&1, 1))}
    end)
  end
```

But this is difficult to read and seems overwrought. I assume there is a cleaner way using some built-in function I don't know about. Is there a better, or more idiomatic, way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

*Further requirements*

Note that I want to group by the person's name, not the entire person object. In this toy example, the person object keys are small, but in practice these could be large nested objects, and for the sake of performance I wouldn't want to use those large objects to do comparisons in the group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need [`Enum.group_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#group_by/2) here, everything might be done in one loop with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension.

```rb
for {%{name: name}, num} <- list, reduce: %{} do
  acc -> Map.update(acc, name, [num], fn old -> [num | old] end)
end
#⇒ %{a: [3, 2, 1], b: [6, 5]}
```

Append to the accumulator in [`Map.update/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html#update/4) if you need your results ordered.

```rb
for {%{name: name}, num} <- list, reduce: %{} do
  acc -> Map.update(acc, name, [num], &Kernel.++(&1, [num]))
end
#⇒ %{a: [1, 2, 3], b: [5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
I forgot about the new [Enum.group_by/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) function, which is exactly what you need here and much more concise. Just do:

```
pairs
|> Enum.group_by(&elem(&1, 0), &elem(&1, 1))
|> Map.to_list()
```

---

*Obsolete Answer:* There is a fabulous explanation in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35418893/4138739

The fast version combines a `reduce/3` function with a `Dict` as sort-of `group_by` function. In order to receive your exact output, you'd have to tweak the `EnumHelpers`-Module in the following way:

```
defp group_one({key, val}, categories) do
    Map.update(categories, key, [val], & &1 ++ [val])
end
```

1. We use `Map.update/4` instead of `Dict.update/4` since the `Dict` function was deprecated.
2. We use `& &1 ++ [val]` instead of `&[val|&1]`, because this gives us the values in the right order `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `[3, 2, 1]`.

**Note:** It is slow to add an element to the **end** of a list `[1, 2] ++ [3]` and much faster to prepend it to the beginning of a list `[3] ++ [1, 2]` as explained in the [Docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.7.3/List.html) (search for *"Due to their cons cell based representation..."*)

Therefore, if the order of the values is not important to you, I'd recommend using the `&[val|&1]` version since this will build your value List with constant time.

---

Therefore, the code would look like this:

```
defmodule EnumHelpers do
  defp group_one({key, val}, categories) do
    Map.update(categories, key, [val], & &1 ++ [val])
  end

  def map_col_fast(coll) do
    Enum.reduce(coll, %{}, &group_one/2)
  end
end

pairs
  |> EnumHelpers.map_col_fast()
  |> Map.to_list()
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response, but I'm looking for a solution that is _less_ overwrought, not more, so what you have listed in what you marked as an obsolete answer is much worse to me than what I already have. Unfortunately, your concise solution doesn't help me either, because I have noted that I am grouping by the name of each person, not the entire person object. I'll go ahead and emphasize that requirement in my question for other readers.